# How to copy all files with given suffix to similar directory tree preserving paths?

Tags: svn, batch-file, windows-xp

I am trying to preserve my modified project files in a source tree and wish to copy from one branch to another without using SVN since I don't typically check in my project files. I wan't to preserve my local modifications (output, intermediate paths, and the like) and persist them to different source tree's so I can easily switch branches with the `subst` command then run my (new) batch file and voila, all my project files will be persisted as well, without using SVN.

For example:

```
<trunk>\MyProject\Project0\Project0.proj
<trunk>\MyProject\Project1\Project1.proj
<trunk>\MyProject\Project2\Project2.proj
```

Needs to be copied over to

```
<branch>\MyProject\Project0\Project0.proj
<branch>\MyProject\Project1\Project1.proj
<branch>\MyProject\Project2\Project2.proj
```

Any crafty batch scripter's out there know how to do this cleverly? I'm thinking `xcopy` with some manipulations to the `/MIR` option? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ROBOCOPY`, it's much more powerful than `XCOPY`.